# Show/Hide Divs from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

This one is really straightforward but I somehow cannot get my head around it.

I have a Bootstrap Dropdown Menu with 3 Choices.

My page will be hosting 3 divs which should be hidden by default.

When clicking on one of the choice within the Dropdown, then I want the related div to appear.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn bg-dark text-light dropdown-toggle rounded-bottom" style="border-radius: 0 !important;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Secure Acceptance Silent Order POST / Checkout API</button>
    <div id="target" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button value="1" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using Transaction Endpoint</button>
        <button value="2" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using iFrame Transaction Endpoint</button>
        <button value="3" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale with Token Creation</button>
    </div>
</div>
        
<div id="1" class="SAformX hidden" style="background-color:red;">
    <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
</div>
<div id="2" class="SAformY hidden" style="background-color:blue;">
    <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
</div>
<div id="3" class="SAformZ hidden" style="background-color:green;">
    <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
</div>
```

By default, the forms with the class hidden are to be hidden :

```
<style>
    .hidden{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Using Vanilla Javascript, I want to generate a Node of elements containing the class Master which is related to each button/chocie within the dropdown. And then, I want to pass its related ID to another function where :

- All divs will be reset to hidden by default
- Then the div with the ID related to the button clicked would appear.

This way, everytime you click on a dropdown choice, the page "soft reset" and hides all the divs that were not selected.

Javascript :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelectorAll('.master').forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const id = item.value;
                MasterMenuToggle(id);
            });
        });
    })
function MasterMenuToggle(id) {

    document.querySelectorAll('.SAform').forEach(item => {
        item.className = "hidden";
    })
    document.getElementById(id).className = "visible"
}
</script>
```

The issue here is the "reset" part of my function MasterMenuToggle

```
document.querySelectorAll('.SAform').forEach(item => {
    item.className = "hidden";
})
```

Clicking on a dropdown item do make its related div appear but then they keep on appearing without the other hiding.

- I do not have a set design yet so "breaking/changing" the class name would kill any formatting I might add to them. They do appear because the page cannot apply the visibility:hidden since the class changed. But if I had like "class="hidden pt-2 border bg-black", then the JS would update the className to "class="visible" killing the rest of the Bootstrap classes.

Can I loop through the IDs to simply ADD an inline CSS to each DIV to be safe?

- The forEach in my reset part of the JS code is the blocker and generates console errors. I do not understand why since even console.log(item) instead of changing the className to hidden would not work.

Hope you can help !

Comment: `id` cannot start with a number, that renders your HTML invalid. Also I suggest you work with `hidden` property instead of recreating it with your own CSS class `.hidden`. That allows you to do `item.hidden = true;`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the classList.add or classList.remove function.

So if you want to reveal, use the remove to remove the hidden, else use the .add to hide again.

E.g. item.classList.add("hidden"); or item.classList.remove("hidden")

There are plenty of actions you can perform with classList which state here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

You used the code for hide all divs

```
function MasterMenuToggle(id) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.SAform').forEach(item => {
        item.className = "hidden";
    })
}
```

But your div's class names are "SAformX", "SAformY" and "SAformZ". So the querySelectorAll('.SAform') cannot found any div. You can add "SAform" class name to your hidden divs.

*Sorry for my bad English :/

Here is working JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7nf18dr6/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
hiddenDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.SAform');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    hiddenDivs.forEach((x) => x.classList.add('.hidden'));
    document.querySelectorAll('.master').forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const id = item.value;
            MasterMenuToggle(id);
        });
    });
});
function MasterMenuToggle(id) {
    hiddenDivs.forEach((x) => {
        if (x.id == id) {
            x.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            x.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn bg-dark text-light dropdown-toggle rounded-bottom" style="border-radius: 0 !important;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Secure Acceptance Silent Order POST / Checkout API
        </button>
        <div id="target" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <button value="1" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using Transaction Endpoint</button>
            <button value="2" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using iFrame Transaction Endpoint</button>
            <button value="3" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale with Token Creation</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="1" class="SAform " style="background-color:red;">
        <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="SAform " style="background-color:blue;">
        <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="SAform " style="background-color:green;">
        <p>gergeyherghdesghderh</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is quite simple if you break it down into two stages. The first stage is to hide all `div` elements when one of the three buttons is clicked and then show the relevant div based upon `value` & `data-id` of the button and div respectively. Rather than using a new class (`hidden`) you can use the inline declaration `display='none'` instead or, as suggested above by @connexo, use `hidden=true` ~ though I think there is a difference in how these are represented on the page with one occupying no space and the other will.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div#target > button').forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        let col=document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id]');
            col.forEach( div=>{ div.style.display='none' } )
            
        document.querySelector('div[ data-id="'+this.value+'"]').style.display='block'
    })
})
```

```css
/* css here only to prettify things */
div{ padding:0.25rem; color:white }
button{padding:0.5rem;margin:0.25rem;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn bg-dark text-light dropdown-toggle rounded-bottom" style="border-radius: 0 !important;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Secure Acceptance Silent Order POST / Checkout API
    </button>
    
    <div id="target" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button value="1" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using Transaction Endpoint</button>
        <button value="2" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale using iFrame Transaction Endpoint</button>
        <button value="3" class="master dropdown-item" type="button">Auth/Sale with Token Creation</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- HTML element IDs cannot begin with a number, use a dataset attribute instead -->
<div data-id=1 class="SAformX hidden" style="background-color:red;">
    <p>Red div - data-id=1</p>
</div>

<div data-id=2 class="SAformY hidden" style="background-color:blue;">
    <p>Blue div - data-id=2</p>
</div>

<div data-id=3 class="SAformZ hidden" style="background-color:green;">
    <p>Green div - data-id=3</p>
</div>
```